# How do I traverse up the DOM to target an element?

Tags: javascript, html

The `parentElement` method returns the parent element from a child element.

e.g `document.querySelector('span').parentElement`

EDIT:
I want to find the `DIV` element using one of its ***children***, ***grand children*** or ***grand children's children***, etc...

```
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>
      <span></span>
    </strong>
  </p>
</div>

<label></label>
<button></button>
```

Expected output:

`p` is a child of `div`

`strong` is a grandchild of `div`

`span` is a grandchild's child of `div`

`label` is not a child of `div`

`button` is not a child of `div`

EDIT:
How do I find DIV using one of its ***nested*** elements?

Comment: `document.querySelector('span').parentElement.children`

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to describe the question.

Comment: The parent of `span` is `strong`, not `div`. `div` is the great-grandparent.

Comment: `strong` is not a child of `div`, it's a grandchild. I think you need to refresh your understanding of parent and child relationships.

Comment: @JohnSimon I have edited your question, if it is not what you intended, please let me know and I will try to embellish the proper intent in your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***childNodes*** to get the childNodes of the DIV element

```js
// document.querySelector will get the FIRST occurence of a DIV element in the DOM.
document.querySelector('div').childNodes.forEach(node => {
  if(node.tagName){
    console.log(`${node.tagName} is a child of ${document.querySelector('div').tagName}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>
      <span></span>
    </strong>
  </p>
  <section>
    <img src="#">
  </section>
  <div>
    <strong>
      <span></span>
    </strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think you may be looking to get the `div` element traversing up the parent's, parent's, parent, etc until you get to the ***DIV*** in relation to the ***SPAN*** tag ***=>*** you can use `closest()`.

```
document.querySelector('SPAN').closest('DIV')
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('SPAN').tagName + '\'s closest DIV up the DOM chain of elements is, DIV with id of ' + document.querySelector('SPAN').closest('DIV').id)
```

```html
<div id="top-level-div">
  <p>
    <strong>
      <span></span>
    </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest()` solved my problem. My question is poorly formulated, can anyone edit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `<strong>` and `<span>` elements are not child elements of the `<div>` that they are nested in, they are grandchildren.

Having said that you can find all the children and grandchildren of a the div element in your example by using the following:

```
document.querySelector("span").closest("div").getElementsByTagName("*")
```

You can then convert the resulting HTMLCollection into an array like this:

```
const childEls = Array.from(document.querySelector("span").closest("div").getElementsByTagName("*"));
```

Comment: `.closest` is really nice. `The closest() method searches up the DOM tree for the closest element which matches a specified CSS selector. It starts at the element itself, then tests the parent, grandparent, and so on until a match is found. If a match is not found, this method returns null. `